# Question concerning equivalent capacitance

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, thevenin

[image]

For the question above, i'm confused as to why the 6uF and 3uF capacitors have the same charge.

Also, for part b, would you have to find v(t) at the 10uF capacitor? If not, what would be the other approach?

Comment: The series capacitors have the same current flowing through them, hence accumulate the same charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6uF and series 3uF act as a Capacitor Voltage divider.  This is true for DC and AC ( unless they have some unusual leakage)

The smaller 3uF thus rises to 2/3 of 10V  so ...   as Zc is inverse to C

- for 3uF, CV= 2/3 * 10V * 3uF = 20 uC
- for 6uF, CV= 1/3 * 10V * 6uF = 20 uC
- however the 4uF , CV= 4uF * -30V= -120 uC

Total charge = 20uC - 120uC = -100uC
Net Cequiv =   __ ( you do)
Net Vc = - __

Now you can fill in the blanks.
Bottom rail assumed =0V